# *Ngif for all columns except last 2 Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to use *Ngif for all columns except last 2, I've been trying to do it for hours but nothings working so far
mes variable has the number of the current month.
`listaMonthsNames` has the same number of elements as the current month
check variable is a boolean set to false

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let month of listaMonthsNames let idx=index">
      <th class="col-{{idx}}" *ngIf="check">{{month}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I also got a checkbox when I click on it shows all months of the array `listaMonthsNames` and if I click it again it hides all months but I want it to leave last 2 months visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to apply ngFor to exclude columns, you can use slice pipe:

```
<....*ngFor="let month of listaMonthsNames | slice: mySlicer"...>
```

where `mySlicer` can have values  from  `0` - include all - to  `listaMonthsNames.length` - exclude all, and any `N` number in `[0;listaMonthsNames.length]` interval to exclude first N number columns,  e.g.:  `2` - to exclude first two columns, as in this [demo example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5bect?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: is there a way to toggle between hide and show options?

Comment: You can use a property, instead of 2 (for example). Then change its value to 0 to include all, and length+1 for nothing, and anything between.See the updated demo

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try it

Comment: Ok, let me know how it went :)